# Cisco SG300 switch with VLANS

Tags: switch, vlan

I have a SonicWall firewall configured with 3 vlans on virtual interfaces on one physical interface. I have a wireless access point configured with 3 wireless networks configured to each of the three vlans. That is all working well.

I purchased a cisco SG300 switch with the purpose of having an ethernet connection to one of the vlans. I'm having trouble getting this to work and could use some pointers.

I think that I need to configure one of the ports to automatically tag any traffic passing through it with correct VLAN tag. Is this the right understanding?

Comment: Yuk. Cisco Small Business products.

Comment: Why the close votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason,

Yes that is true. You need to configure your interface on SG300 to pass through the vlan network. Here is what you can do.

1> Log onto to the SG300, either console or ssh

a> show interface status  { verify if the interface you connected is up }

b> Create a vlan.

c> Configure the interface in switchport mode with above vlan updated to the access list.